# I have JSP page form , if user clicks on the submit button then that JSP should pass the values to Java class how can i do this?

Tags: java, jsp

I have JSP page form , if user clicks on the submit button then that JSP should pass the values to Java class(not servlet) how can i do this?

Comment: Just create a servlet which collects the request parameter values and passes them further to that class the usual Java way?

Comment: E.g. `yourClass.doSomething(request.getParameter("foo"))` inside the servlet's `doPost()` or so. If you fear servlets because of sheer ignorance, just start at [our servlets wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).

Comment: This forum encourages the research effort which you might have done in pursuance of your problem. Instead of directly asking a question, you are better advised to first search. The question asked is very common and very basic and you should have been able to get the answer for this across the internet. A code snippet showing your effort or ways you tried to achieve desired result might be more useful for others and will also prompt other users to answer quickly .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You either need to use Servlet or JSP. If don't want Servlet then create another JSP.
For e.g. `otherJsp.jsp` having only scriplet as follow:

```
<%
        MyClass obj = new MyClass();
    obj.myMethod(request.getParameterMap());
%>
```

MyClass is your class where you want to send parameters.
on submit click of your jsp, call action as `otherJsp.jsp`

Comment: Yeah...I know it is a bad practice....but can you explain without using `servlet` how will you pass parameters to Java class at server ??

Comment: By creating a servlet. OP merely said that he has a Java class which is not a servlet. OP didn't said that he don't want to use a servlet. Well, a servlet **is** the answer to his question. It is able to collect request parameters and it is as being a fullworthy Java class able to invoke arbitrary Java classes/methods the usual Java way.

Comment: @BalusC - Totally agree....from question I assume that he don't want to use servlet.....